# I am trying to link 2 tables in Power BI. Lookup table has some of the items in Upper/ Lower cases that I am trying to link with main table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables, 1 is my item table and other one is master data table.
My table has some items which are not always comes in a right order. Sometimes, it's been entered in lower cases or upper cases, whereas it is viceversa in the master data table.

What could be the possible solutions for this?

I have tried adding upper and lower case columns in PBI

Comment: Please add some example tables with rows so we can see. You said you " tried adding upper and lower case columns" - what was the result?